# How to call an iframe to do something?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

Here is the situation....
I have a iframe, which is located to my client side, and the iframe content is in my server. 
So, when the user do something, my iframe will appear, and they can type something, and post to my server. But the question is....The iframe itself can't disappear. 
The only thing I want to do, is submit and hide the iframe. I can do a button in my client side to hide my iframe, but the iframe can't control the js in the client side. And the client side also can't control button on my iframe. 
So, I am thinking to make a button in the client side, and some kind of command to submit the button....But the question is how can I do so? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The iframe and the parent document can communicate through javascript:

- the iframe is available to the document like this: `window.frames["iframe_name"]`. This is the `window` object of the iframe, from here on you can do just about anything with js.
- the parent document's window is available to the iframe through `window.opener`. Again, this is the `window` of the parent document.

Maybe [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/251420/invoking-javascript-in-iframe-from-parent-page) helps you too.

Comment: umum , still don't understand, let say I have a button call "test" inside the iframe, how can I call the "test" button click() action outside the iframe.

Comment: @Ted `window.frames["iframe_name"].document.getElementById('iframe_button').click()`

Comment: I see, but why using the square backet instead?

Comment: @Ted because `window.frames` is an array-like structure, it contains _all_ the frames. If you only have that iframe in your page, you can use `window.frames[0]`.

Comment: Glabi, I love u, u save me I lots of time. XD.

Answer (score 0):

for even more robustness:

```
function getIframeWindow(iframe_object) {
  var doc;

  if (iframe_object.contentWindow) {
    return iframe_object.contentWindow;
  }

  if (iframe_object.window) {
    return iframe_object.window;
  } 

  if (!doc && iframe_object.contentDocument) {
    doc = iframe_object.contentDocument;
  } 

  if (!doc && iframe_object.document) {
    doc = iframe_object.document;
  }

  if (doc && doc.defaultView) {
   return doc.defaultView;
  }

  if (doc && doc.parentWindow) {
    return doc.parentWindow;
  }

  return undefined;
}
```

and

```
...
var el = document.getElementById('iframe_id');
// or
var el = window.frames["iframe_name"];
// or
var el = window.frames[0];

var frame_win = getIframeWindow(el);

if (frame_win) {
  frame_win.targetFunction();
  ...
}
...
```